Publish message to Kafka topic (KRaft) with Dapr C#
I'm new to Dapr as well as Kafka. I want to implement Dapr with Kafka(KRaft) for my .NET 8 desktop app. I'm working on POC, there I'm facing issue:

'Dapr.DaprException: 'Publish operation failed: the Dapr endpoint
indicated a failure'. ({"Status(StatusCode="Unavailable",
Detail="Error connecting to subchannel.",
DebugException="System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection
could be made because the target machine actively refused it.")"}).

docker-compose.yaml for Kafka image in Docker
version: "3.8"

services:
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.7
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
      - "./kafka.keystore.jks:/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks"
      - "./kafka.truststore.jks:/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks"
    environment:
      # KRaft settings
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka:9093
      # Listeners
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
      # Additional settings
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=127.0.0.1
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS="kafka-topic:1:1"

volumes:
  kafka_data:
    driver: local

Program.cs
using Dapr.Client;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var daprClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DaprClient>();

        var message = new HelloMessage { Text = "Hello, Kafka!" };
        await PublishMessageEvent(daprClient, message);
    }

    //const string topicName = "kafka-topic";

    const string PUBSUB_NAME = "kafka-pubsub";
    const string TOPIC_NAME = "kafka-topic";
    static async Task PublishMessageEvent(DaprClient daprClient, HelloMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            await daprClient.PublishEventAsync(PUBSUB_NAME, TOPIC_NAME, message);

            Console.WriteLine("Event published successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error publishing event: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
    static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string daprPort = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DAPR_GRPC_PORT")!;
        var grpcEndpoint = $"http://localhost:{daprPort}";
        //var grpcEndpoint = $"http://localhost:52540";

        // var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:5009/");
        // Register DaprClient instance using gRPC channel and DaprClientBuilder
        var daprClient = new DaprClientBuilder()
            .UseGrpcEndpoint(grpcEndpoint) // Specify the gRPC endpoint
            .Build();

        services.AddSingleton(daprClient);
    }
}

public class HelloMessage
{
    public string Text { get; set; } = default!;
}

Kafka pubsub yaml (Dapr configuration)
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: kafka-pubsub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.kafka
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: brokers
    value: "localhost:9092"
  - name: consumerGroup
    value: "my-group"
  - name: authRequired
    value: "false"
  - name: disableTls
    value: "true"

I have turned it off firewall. What am I really missing here?

The issue you are experiencing is because your Dapr component is pointing to a Kafka instance hosted at localhost when in reality, your app is running a containerised environment alongside another container named kafka.
So, if you'd like to get this working, you'd update your Dapr component as follows:
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: kafka-pubsub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.kafka
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: brokers
    value: "kafka:9092"
  - name: consumerGroup
    value: "my-group"
  - name: authRequired
    value: "false"
  - name: disableTls
    value: "true"

Then simply compose down and back up again and your app should connect just fine :)
